# How can I interlace functions in Javascript with conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my problem:
I'm programming a little game where you need to connect numbers, which are in a table, on your screen with mouse clicks. After you pressed the right number, they will be connected by a line, which is a png file and has 0 width and height. That changes after you clicked the cell with the right number. Now, it works, but you could just press the first cell over and over again to get all the lines. I'm trying for hours now to find a solution, but nothing works for me. 
 Thank you 
Here's the code:

```
cellNumber = 49;
$("#cell_"+cellNumber).click(function()
{
    $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("width", "600px");
    $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("height", "440px");
    cellNumber = 65;
    lineCounter++;
    $("#cell_"+cellNumber).click(function()
    {
        $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("width", "600px");
        $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("height", "440px");
        cellNumber = 110;
        lineCounter++;
        $("#cell_"+cellNumber).click(function()
        {
            $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("width", "600px");
            $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("height", "440px");
            cellNumber = 112;
            lineCounter++;
            $("#cell_"+cellNumber).click(function()
            {
                $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("width", "600px");
                $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("height", "440px");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can increase your chances of getting a good answer by being clear and stating: Your input, the output you got and your expected output.

Comment: some html might make things clearer as well

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest click events, it's counter-intuitive. Click events are bound to objects upon the document ready event and thus must be within the document.ready() function in order to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    cellNumber = 49;
    $("#cell_"+cellNumber).click(function() {
        $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("width", "600px");
        $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("height", "440px");
        cellNumber = 65;
        lineCounter++;
    });
    $("#cell_"+cellNumber).click(function() {
        $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("width", "600px");
        $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("height", "440px");
        cellNumber = 110;
        lineCounter++;
    });
    $("#cell_"+cellNumber).click(function() {
        $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("width", "600px");
        $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("height", "440px");
        cellNumber = 112;
        lineCounter++;
    });
    $("#cell_"+cellNumber).click(function() {
        $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("width", "600px");
        $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("height", "440px");
    });
});
```

Comment: this is not the whole code. it's all in the document ready function. the problem is to get it so, that you need to click them in the specific order.

Comment: @Arkay: your code creates 4 click handlers for an element with id `cell_49` and will never work for anything else... the listener is created for the matching element. Changing cellNumber doesn't magically move the listener to another element.

Answer (score 0):

How about removing click from correctly selected cells;

```
cellNumber = 49;
    $("#cell_"+cellNumber).on('click', function()
    {
        $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("width", "600px");
        $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("height", "440px");
        $("#cell_"+cellNumber).off('click')
        cellNumber = 65;
        lineCounter++;
        $("#cell_"+cellNumber).on('click', function()
        {
            $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("width", "600px");
            $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("height", "440px");
           $("#cell_"+cellNumber).off('click')
            cellNumber = 110;
            lineCounter++;
            $("#cell_"+cellNumber).on('click', function()
            {
                $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("width", "600px");
                $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("height", "440px");
                $("#cell_"+cellNumber).off('click')
                cellNumber = 112;
                lineCounter++;
                $("#cell_"+cellNumber).click(function()
                {
                    $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("width", "600px");
                    $("#line_"+lineCounter).attr("height", "440px");
                });
            });
        });
    });
```